# WiFI routers connected to EdgeRouter to have different IPs

Tags: networking, routing, wan

There's 2 WiFi routers connected to my Edgerouter, my edgerouter gets 3 different WAN IPs but both of those routers only use first one, how do i make so there would be different ip of those two wifi routers? (theres a switch connected to eth1 and both wifi routers are connected to that switch)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your hardware. Research how to setup VLANs on your switch and edge router. Put each WiFi router into a seperate VLAN and tell your edge router to channel traffic from these VLANs over the additional WAN IPs.